# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined Discord

Tags: javascript

Script is for deleting messages via Discord utilizing the ID at the top. When I run the script I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`.Can't seem to figure out how to fix the error I'm getting.

```js
var before = '336607993439453184';
clearMessages = function() {
  const authToken = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token.replace(/"/g, "");
  const channel = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
  const baseURL = `https://discordapp.com/api/channels/${channel}/messages`;
  const headers = {
    "Authorization": authToken
  };

  let clock = 0;
  let interval = 500;

  function delay(duration) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration);
    });
  }

  fetch(baseURL + '?before=' + before + '&limit=100', {
      headers
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(messages => {
      return Promise.all(messages.map((message) => {
        before = message.id;
        return delay(clock += interval).then(() => fetch(`${baseURL}/${message.id}`, {
          headers,
          method: 'DELETE'
        }));
      }));
    }).then(() => clearMessages());
}
clearMessages();
```

Comment: What is `localStorage.token`? In an ideal scenario, this property does't exist in `localStorage`, so you cannot call `replace` on it. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It means `..contentWindow.localStorage.token` does not exist…!?

Answer (score 1):

this is because below mentioned code is **undefined**.

```
typeof document.body.appendChild(document.createElement`iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token == undefined
```

you can only use replace function on string data type

Check you browser **local storage** to see if **token** is present or not.